# Sending x-message-ttl to RabbitMQ through Symfony Messenger

Tags: symfony, rabbitmq

How can I define `x-message-ttl` for a RabbitMQ queue with Symfony Messenger?

I see it is used with the `DelayStamp`, but I don't want to setup a Delay. I would simply like messages to drop if they are not handled within a certain time frame. I don't see it referenced anywhere else in the source code.

The only documentation I can find is for the old method of using the OldSound RabbitMq package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out indirectly through [this PR](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/29532).

`messenger.yaml`

```
framework:
    messenger:
        transports:
            mywork:
                dsn: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'
                options:
                    exchange:
                        name: mywork
                        type: direct
                    queues:
                        mywork:
                            arguments:
                                x-message-ttl: 60000
```